# How to set angularjs ng-repeat on select option

Tags: angularjs

At the moment I have a select, but i need to have custom styling for my options, that requires me to change my setup a bit.

At the moment I have

```
 <select ng-model="vm.selectedStation"
         ng-options="s.stationName for s in  vm.nearbyStations" .....>
 </select>
```

Now I am changing it to

```
<select ng-model="vm.selectedStation">
    <option ng-repeat="s in vm.nearbyStations" value="{{s}}">            
        {{s.stationName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

It visibly shows the same, but the value is different. I require ng-model to be `s`. to be the object, but instead it shows as the `s.stationName` May I ask how do I set the value properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-value` directive:

```
<select ng-model="vm.selectedStation">
    ̶<̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶r̶e̶p̶e̶a̶t̶=̶"̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶v̶m̶.̶n̶e̶a̶r̶b̶y̶S̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶"̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶s̶}̶}̶"̶>̶
    <option ng-repeat="s in vm.nearbyStations" ng-value="s">            
        {{s.stationName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Interpolation with curly brackets `{{ }}` converts the expression to a string. The `ng-value` directive evaluates the expression and retains its type.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `ng-value` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)
- [AngularJS `<select>` - Using `ngValue` to bind the model to an array of objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngvalue-to-bind-the-model-to-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `ng-value` on each `<option>` to assign directly to each constituent of `vm.nearbyStations`.

See an example usage below.

(As an aside, your HTML appears to have an unpaired `</option>`.)

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function () {
    this.nearbyStations = [
      { stationName: 'a' },
      { stationName: 'b' },
      { stationName: 'c' },
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <select ng-model="vm.selectedStation">
    <option ng-repeat="s in vm.nearbyStations" ng-value="s">{{ s.stationName }}</option>
  </select>
  <pre>selectedStation = {{ vm.selectedStation }}</pre>
</div>
```